# Is there any other alternative way to see direct effect of changes made in plugin without UNINSTALL & INSTALL it again and again?

Tags: nopcommerce

I am new to nopcommerce and I am developing a plug-in in it.

I have partially created my plug-in and meanwhile i have found that if i change anything in plug-in's code (View, model, controller, services, etc.) then i have to **UNINSTALL my plug-in and then INSTALL to see the changes.**

It is really tedious task to do.

Is there any other alternative way to see changes especially for designing view where we just need to set our designing.

If it is possible to see changes by just reloading it in browser then it will be great for all.

Please reply if anyone has any idea about that.

All answers are accepted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know all installed plugins are cached into memory so just overwrite .dll in Plugins folder and you can either

1. Restart your application with IIS/WebMatrix
2. Go to Admin > Configuration > Plugins and in top-right corner of the plugins view hit "Reload list of plugins"
3. "Restart application" or maybe even "Clear cache" in top-right corner of the admin page may work too. Try it out.

Comment: #3 is what I always do

Comment: I am testing plugins in localhost. but is there a way to install all plugins bought form nop market at once ?

Comment: I tried the usual reuploading all nop dlls, but this time I had to use your solution no. 2 to get the plugin to reload.

Answer (score 0):

You should clean the solution and then build plugins after making changes to the code of the your plugin.

Comment: I am testing plugins in localhost. but is there a way to install all plugins bought form nop market at once ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a batch-file that I run each time I want to deploy changes to my plugin on my local IIS.  It may be overkill, but it works.  I keep it on my desktop.  When I want to test changes, I right-click and "Run as Administrator".

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO Stopping IIS
iisreset /stop

ECHO Clearing Temporary ASP.Net Files (Server cache)
for /d %%i in ("%systemroot%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\*") do for /d %%j in ("%%i\Temporary ASP.Net Files\*") do RD /q/s "%%j"
for /d %%i in ("%systemroot%\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\*") do for /d %%j in ("%%i\Temporary ASP.Net Files\*") do RD /q/s "%%j"

ECHO Building MyPlugin
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /build Debug "C:\Path_to_Nop_Source\Plugins\MyPlugin\MyPlugin.csproj"

ECHO Deploying MyPlugin
xcopy "C:\Path_to_Nop_Source\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\MyPlugin" "C:\Path_To_WebRoot\Plugins\MyPlugin" /D /Y

ECHO Restarting IIS
iisreset /start

ECHO Done
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

When I ran into this problem I tried restarting everything starting with the app, then the app pool and even iis. Unfortunately it didn't work. What did work however was **rebuilding the site again and copying it over again** (mainly all the nop.core.dll, nop.web.dll etc.). I did copy the core dlls of the site the first time around too, but I guess the plugin was copied after those. I think the important part is that the core dlls need to be recompiled so they appear different to iis and cause the already loaded plugins to get unloaded from memory.

I'm quite sure that restarting the whole server would work too, but who would want to do that?

P.S. I was about to ask the same question, because I couldn't find this one while googling (probably because the title is a little too specific). I intended to name mine **Plugin not updating after copying a newer version**. What lead me to this question was the similar question block that appears when you write a question.

**Update:** So I discovered that sometimes rebuilding and replacing nop core libraries isn't enough. However in that situation using the "Reload list of plugins" option in admin panel did the trick. Another time I was trying to just use that option and it didn't work until I replaced the core libraries. So to reload a plugin one or both of those steps might be required.